# How can I turn this line of HTML into an HTML helper?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
 <input type="text" name="search" id="search" style="border-style:ridge;" />
```

Thats the line of Html I'd like to have it as a html helper.  I tried:

```
@Html.TextBox(" ", "",new { id="search", name="search", style="border-style:ridge;"})
```

but it won't post back for that text box when i press enter.  It works fine for the input tag.

Comment: only "for" helpers (except display) will bind to the model.  Look at @Html.TextBoxFor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would just be a regular box:

```
@Html.TextBox("search", null, new { style = "border-style: ridge;" })
```

Or assuming your model has a `search` property, it would be:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.search, new { style = "border-style: ridge;" })
```

Both of these produce the same HTML. Unless there's any funny stuff going on, both the id and name of the textbox will be `search`.